# Ruby on rails routes - what does the "as" do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In ruby on rails, what does the "as:" do in route?

Example: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html 1.2

You can also generate paths and URLs. If the route above is modified to be:

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'
```

and your application contains this code in the controller:

```
@patient = Patient.find(17)
```

and this in the corresponding view:

```
<%= link_to 'Patient Record', patient_path(@patient) %>
```

Comment: In this concrete case the `as` option is useless (doesn't change anything)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In routes `as:` option is used to make url or path helpers for that particular route. If you look at your route:

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'
```

You have specified `as: 'patient'` which will enable rails to make `patient_path` and `patient_url` helpers

*patient_path will give you **/patient/:id** and patient_url will give you **domain/patient/:id***

If you run rake routes in your terminal it will list all the routes of your application with there corresponding helper methods. For details checkout [**`path and url helpers`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers)

Answer (score 1):

It defines what the route helpers will look like:

```
patient_path(@patient)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `path` name which is generated from your routes

For example, if you have the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :bones, as: :skeleton
```

You'll get routes as `skeleton_path` for the `bones` controller

--

You have to remember that Rails' [routing structure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) is based around "resources" (handled by controllers). Your routes, therefore, should be structured *around* the controllers your application has

If you want to change the "name" of a particular controller path helper (from `bones` to `skeleton` for example), you'll be able to use the `as` option